# Unable to test custom repositories using Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, junit4, spring-boot-test

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.4. Followed the [Spring Boot Test](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) article for unit tests. When I have custom repositories, test is not working and fails with error `UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.jay.UserRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository';`

Here is my code,

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserRepository  {

  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  // sample code for custom repo. can be done easily in CrudRepo
  public User findUser(String name){

    TypedQuery<User> q = entityManager.createQuery("Select u from User u Where u.name = :name", User.class);
    q.setParameter("name", name);

    return q.getSingleResult();
  }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private TestEntityManager entityManager;

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Test
  public void findUserTest(){
    ...
  }
}
```

But I am able to test the following Dao with Spring Boot without any config change,

```
@Transactional
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

  User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

When I am using `@SpringBootTest`, I am able to inject `UserRepository`, but not `TestEntityManager`.

Comment: i think this is also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021902/excluding-spring-integration-from-spring-boot-test-with-spring-boot-1-4?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted the same question in Github of Spring Boot Test and got reply. Refer [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8501)